# rendering of grafics in Pycharm not working with multiple windows

Tags: pycharm, plotly

I use Pycharm Pro 2022.3.3. As soon as I have more than one Pycharm project open (as new window), the rendering of graphs (e.g. plotly in jupyter notebooks, diagram of drawio plugin ... I guess all interactive graphs) are not showing anymore. It only works with the first python project that I opened.

When I close all Pycharm windows, and open the one that didn't work as the first project, everything works properly.

There are several issues of rendering problems in Pycharm, but none of those point to the problem with several open Pycharm projects.